# How to extract all the variable of one type (string, int...) in a .py file?

Tags: python, gettext

I thought of using `pygettext3 -d`, but you have to run it in cmd. I don't know how I could run it in my code.

And I also need to manipulate the strings, like to surround strings with `_()` to do the localisation (that's how gettext library works).

My problem's like:

```
def b (foo, bar):
    if foo:  
        print ('FOOBAR')
    elif bar:  
        print ('FOObar')
    else:
        print ('foobar')
        raise ValueError ('fooBAR')
```

So I'm just curious how do I extract strings like`'FOOBAR' 'FOObar' 'foobar' 'fooBAR'`. To save them a list and do stuff to the original string, like surround them with _(). So `'FOObar'`  becomes `_('FOObar' )`

Comment: As far as I know, you have to convert your script files manually. You might be able to partially automate the process to some degree yourself using a regular expressions, but I suspect it would be problematic.

Answer (score 0):

Use os module to change directory to the folder. Then import the local string files from it.

```
import os
sys.chdir(directory_name)
from filename.locals import *
```

This would be useful if all variables are strings. Do tell whether this trick works.

Comment: Thanks a lot for sharing your code. But i think might not be what I want. I updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out with the help of [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@SergioPaniego/abstract-syntax-trees-in-python-ast-library-9bfd705ef9f1), this [tutorial](https://medium.com/@kamneemaran45/python-ast-5789a1b60300) and [r/kellyjonbrazil](https://www.reddit.com/user/kellyjonbrazil) on reddit:

```
import ast

class MyVisitor (ast.NodeVisitor):
    def visit_Str (self, node):
        print ('String Node: ' + node.s)


class MyTransformer (ast.NodeTransformer):
    def visit_Str (self, node):
        return ast.Str (node.s)

# f could just be a string.
with open ('test.py', encoding = 'utf-8-sig') as f:
    parsed = ast.parse (f.read ())

# MyTransformer ().visit (parsed)
MyVisitor ().visit (parsed)
```

For my case:

```
import ast

code = '''
def b (foo, bar):
    if foo:
        print ('FOOBAR')
    elif bar:
        print ('FOObar')
    else:
        print ('foobar')
        raise ValueError ('fooBAR')
'''


class MyVisitor (ast.NodeVisitor):
    def visit_Str (self, node):
        print ('String Node: ' + node.s)


parsed = ast.parse (code)

MyVisitor ().visit (parsed)
```

Output:

```
String Node: FOOBAR
String Node: FOObar
String Node: foobar
String Node: fooBAR
```